# SQL - Where clause: comparing a column with multiple values

Tags: sql

Is there any generic command or syntax in `SQL` to allow one to have multiple values in a where statement without using `OR`?
`OR` just gets tedious when you have many values to choose from and you only want say half of them.
I want to return only columns that contain certain values. I am using `Cache SQL`, but as I said, a generic syntax might be helpful as well because most people are unfamiliar with `Cache SQL`. Thanks!

Comment: select 
 Answer
from
 Stackoverflow
where 
 Username in ('Mr. Alien', 'Andrew Logvinov', 'sjramsay', 'Oded')

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `IN`:

```
... where column_name in ('val1', 'val2', ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'IN' clause.

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE productid IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [`IN` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx).

> Determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery or a list.